# how to use command systemctl restart elasticsearch in linux?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I searched the errors on Google and referred to them, but I couldn't solve the problem.

How can I do systemctl restart elasticsearch.
Can I use the service command?

`elasticsearch.yml` (/etc/elasticsearch)

```
node.name: node-1
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
```

`systemctl status elasticsearch.service`
[image]

command use but error occured (pic1)
[image]

[image]

`journalctl -xe`

```
May 27 06:36:54 elk sshd[29380]: Invalid user administrator from 36.65.172.36 port 55685
May 27 06:36:55 elk sshd[29380]: Connection closed by invalid user administrator 36.65.172.36 port 55685 [preauth]
May 27 06:36:59 elk sudo[29399]: injekim97 : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart elasticsearch.service
May 27 06:36:59 elk sudo[29399]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by injekim97(uid=0)
May 27 06:36:59 elk systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
-- Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 3563.
May 27 06:36:59 elk systemd-entrypoint[29402]: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 87: /etc/default/elasticsearch: Permission denied
May 27 06:36:59 elk systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit elasticsearch.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
May 27 06:36:59 elk systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit elasticsearch.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
May 27 06:36:59 elk systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
-- Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 3563 and the job result is failed.
May 27 06:36:59 elk sudo[29399]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 27 06:37:03 elk sshd[29463]: Invalid user administrator from 36.65.172.36 port 55888
May 27 06:37:03 elk sshd[29463]: Connection closed by invalid user administrator 36.65.172.36 port 55888 [preauth]
```

`my attempt`

- May 27 06:36:59 elk systemd-entrypoint[29402]: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 87: /etc/default/elasticsearch: Permission denied

  `sudo chown -R user:user /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin`

-> but error occured

> **how to use command `systemctl restart elasticsearch` in linux?**

**CarbonRK update post**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you do an `ls -l` on the directory? Make sure it is owned by elasticsearch. Try this command `sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /etc/default/elasticsearch`. Remember also that Elasticsearch cannot start from root when build as source.

Comment: @Python-97 please go through the answer and let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Screen captured using `ls -l` command. It also used the chown-R command, but systemctl restart elasticsearch.The service is not working.

Comment: @Python-97 if I understand your update correctly it looks like Elasticsearch isn't an owner of the /etc/elasticsearch folder so it hasn't got rights to make any operations here. For the check reason try run chmod -r 777 /etc/elasticsearch command and then try to run service. What is the difference in your /etc/elasticsearch and /etc/default/elasticsearch directories? Do you have more than one node on your VM? You executed commands in 3 different directories :-)

Comment: vm has only one node.
elastic search.yml discovery.type: signle-node.

Comment: What is the difference between the /etc/elastic search directory and the /etc/default/elastic search directory?
answer: I didn't know how to verify that elasticsearch is owned, so I did it.

Comment: @Python-97 Run run chmod -r 777 and chown -r elasticsearch:elasticsearch on both directories and then try to start elasticsearch service. It looks like there are installed 2 instances of elasticsearch in two different directories. Maybe this caused your problem. How did you install your ES? Did you use archive or other method? And finally did you follow official ES guide to install it?